# Setting GPU rendering: CVMCompiler has now run for 5 hours

Tags: gpu, osx

I've got an AMD 6750M graphics card with 1 GB of VRAM and Blender 2.79. I successfully selected the card as a GPU target in the user preferences.

When starting my render, Blender says: `Loading render kernels`

According to Activity Monitor a process named CVMCompiler has now been running for over five hours. That surely is more than a few minutes?

The rest of macOS is practically unusable, as it seems most things are reliant on the GPU. When I force quit the process, other apps, including Safari, become responsive immediately.

What could be the issue? I can't see any signs of any errors, but where should I look to find any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

5 Hours loading kernel doesn't sound right, that should be the first indication that something is wrong.

Anyway your graphics card is too old and unsupported.

As stated in the [Official Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#opencl) only cards with GCN (Graphics Core Next) 2.0 or above are supported. 
That means Radeon HD 7790 and above, as stated in the linked [Wikpedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#API_Overview)

The AMD 6750 is no longer supported. Also 1Gb of memory is very low for today's standards and you probably wouldn't get any benefit from GPU rendering anyway

Comment: I did read through the docs, and noticed the lack GCN 2.0, but when the card appeared in the user settings I just went with it. I’ll accept “don’t even bother” as the answer to my question, thank you!