# How do I enable GPU rendering for Radeon 5870 in Linux?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I am running Ubuntu 18.04, I use blender 2.79, and my GPU is an ATI Radeon HD 5870.

I am really hoping someone here can help me with setting up GPU rendering. I have installed many different libraries, but I still cant get blender to recognize my GPU.

Can someone please help? I would *really* appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling GPU rendering for Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles)

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos I already tried that XD

Comment: @cegaton thanks, but that wont work because I am running linux, not windows.

Comment: The card needs to be GCN 2 or above https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Render/Cycles/OpenCL

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98109/setting-gpu-rendering-cvmcompiler-has-now-run-for-5-hours